# "make things look better" and more detail

Tags: word-choice

A basic sentence:

> They make things look better than they are.

So far, it seems ok. But now I would like to be more specific:

> They make things look better on TV or on posters than they are.

And it looks awkward for me and I guess it is wrong. Is it? If so, how can I convey information from the first sentence alongside details about TV and posters?

Answer (score 1):

It would sound better if you made "TV and posters" the subject instead of the ambiguous "they":

> TV and posters make things look better than they are.

or as @JasonBassford comments, to be more specific about *who* on TV and the posters makes things look better,

> People in ads on TV and posters make things look better than they are.

Comment: But let's assume that we talk about people or ads, not TV/posters itself, therefore there is "they".

Comment: @ziolek *People on TV and ads on posters make things look better than they are.*

Comment: I like @JasonBassford's answer.

Comment: @Mixolydian Feel free to add it to your answer. I was just providing commentary. :)